# C++ getInt() function (have a java equivalent attached)

Tags: c++

I'm admittedly not the most experienced with C++, but am surprised to be having issues with getting such a simple function to work properly.  All I'm wanting is a function to get a user's input and ensure it obtains an integer(without crashing due to unexpected input) and then return that value to the calling function.  It should not accept any special characters or spaces whatsoever.  Essentially, I want it to be just like the Java equivalent that I'll post below:

```
public static int getInt()
{
    boolean isNum = false; //test variable
    String str; //to hold input

    do
    {
        str = keyboard.nextLine();
        if (!(isNum = str.matches("\\d+")))
        {
            System.out.println("Enter a valid whole number, try again.");
        }
    } while(!isNum);

    return Integer.parseInt(str);
}
```

Comment: What is the *specific* problem you're facing? (AKA "we won't just write the code for you").

Comment: What about cin>>intValue; does not work for you?

Comment: using cin >> int; works....as long as expected input is entered.  If I enter text characters, I get stuck in an infinite loop though, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just try to read an `int` with `cin >> [int variable]`, and make sure it succeeded. If not, wash, rinse, and repeat:

```
int i;

while (!(cin >> i)) {
    cout << "Enter a valid integer, try again: ";
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(), '\n');
}

return i;
```

That will work, but will return `12` when given input like

> 12 a

because it will read the 12 and stop at `a`. If you do not want to just "get as much as you can" and want to read the whole line (which is what the Java snippet apparently does) then you can use `std::getline` and try to convert the resulting string into an integer with `std::stoi`:

```
string line;
int integer = 0;

while (std::getline(cin, line))
    try {
        integer = std::stoi(line);
        break;
    } catch (...) {
        cout << "Enter an integer, try again: ";
    }

return integer;
```

That way will *not* return on input like

> 143 bbc

because it will try to convert the entire line `143 bbc` to an integer and tell the user to try again because `bbc` can't be converted to an integer. It will only return when the entire line is integer input.

You can actually accomplish this by using regexen like the Java example does, but I think it's a waste to pull out regexes for this simple task.

Edit:

If you want to reject decimal input instead of truncating it, you can convert the input to a `double` and check to make sure it doesn't have a decimal part:

```
string line;
double d = 0;

while (std::getline(cin, line))
    try {
        d = std::stod(line);

        if (std::fmod(d, 1) != 0)
            throw 0;

        break;
    } catch (...) {
        cout << "Enter an integer, try again: ";
    }

return d;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The second code block you listed is essentially what I wanted. It catches when any letters are input and prevents an infinite loop. The only issue I see now is when I put in a decimal type number it will accept that input and truncate the decimal portion instead of getting new input. I'm going to try and figure out what the problem is there ...I'm assuming it's something with the stoi function possibly, I'll have to look through the library documentation for it.

Comment: @R.Brown use `std::stod` instead to convert it to a double, then if successful, cast it to an `int` when you return it, and that will truncate it.

Comment: It's already truncating it.  I'm intending for it to reject decimal input or really anything that isn't input in an integer format.

Comment: Just to clarify, it's accepting input such as 2.33 and returning it as 2....truncating the .33 decimal portion.